# A good source to learn refinement of Nash Equilibrium and Bayesian Games

Tags: reference-request, game-theory, bayesian, nash-equilibrium

I am studying the computation of various refinements of Nash Equilibrium in pure and mixed strategies, which includes Weakly Perfect Bayesian Equilibrium and Sequential Equilibrium. Also, I want to look into Bayesian Games and Bayesian Nash Equilibrium. I am having a hard time finding a good book that covers these topics. Most books cover undergraduate topics or specialized topics that are too  involved. Could anyone here please suggest a few titles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic intro econ PhD textbook for microeconomics is [MWG](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0195073401), the chapters in that related to game theory are probably a good place to start.

Other good game theory textbooks include [Fudenberg and Tirole](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262061414), [Myerson](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0674341163), and [Osborne and Rubinstein](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262650401).

Happy hunting!